# Kafka connector (HDFS SINK) not working after initial update

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect

We are using kafka 0.10.2.0 and trying to use HDFS Sink connector to push the data from Kafka to HDFS. This succeeds only for the first time and after that no update is happening. Also, the Kafka standalone connector log has:

```
[2017-09-01 19:20:03,030] INFO WorkerSinkTask{id=hdfs-sinks-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:272)
[2017-09-01 19:20:03,034] WARN Commit of WorkerSinkTask{id=hdfs-sinks-0} offsets timed out (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:172)
```

Below are the properties added as suggested in one of the forums.

```
name=hdfs-sinks 
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector 
tasks.max=1 
topics=mysql-author 
hdfs.url=hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020 
flush.size=3 
logs.dir=/hdfs_directory/data/log 
request.timeout.ms=310000 
offset.flush.interval.ms=5000 
heartbeat.interval.ms=60000 
session.timeout.ms=300000 
max.poll.records=100
```

Connector Config:

```
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets  
offset.flush.interval.ms=120000 
offset.flush.timeout.ms=60000 
buffer.memory=100
```

Comment: What is your flush.size? Maybe post the full connector and worker config?

Comment: @dawsaw Please refer the below worker Config along with flush size:
name=hdfs-sinks
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=mysql-author
hdfs.url=hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020
flush.size=3
logs.dir=/hdfs_directory/data/log
request.timeout.ms=310000
offset.flush.interval.ms=5000
heartbeat.interval.ms=60000
session.timeout.ms=300000
max.poll.records=100

Connector Config:
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
offset.flush.interval.ms=120000
offset.flush.timeout.ms=60000
buffer.memory=100

Comment: what is the rate at which data comes into the mysql-author topic? the flush.size config suggests that you will flush to HDFS every 3 messages.